# Energy and intensity of a radiation

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, radiation

I have a question about the difference between energy and intensity of a radiation, I have read the energy is the one that the photons have of the radiation and the intensity increases with the number of photons. However, as the number of photons increases, so does the energy, according to $E=nhν$ and on the other hand the intensity is defined as $I=E/St$, i.e. according to the formula, the intensity is related to the energy, not to the number of photons.

Comment: the first is quantum mechanics, the second classical electrodynamics. If you divide the classical energy by hnu you will get the number of photons that make it up.

Answer (score 1):

By combining your equations, we get $$I=\frac{nh\nu}{St}$$
where $I$ is intensity, $n$ is number of photons, $h$ is Planck's constant, $\nu$ is frequency, and $t$ is time.
By substituting the equation for energy, we show a direct relationship between number of photons and intensity of light.